# MSAL SignUp not returning access token for local accounts

Tags: xamarin, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I've followed the tutorial code linked here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/azure-ad-b2c

But when signing up (which isn't covered in detail in above link), the AuthenticationResult returns a null access_token. Is there perhaps a b2C setting that I'm missing?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to represent a resource to obtain an access token for using app registrations 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-desktop-app-webapi?tabs=app-reg-ga

You need to ask for a scope in the MSAL code to get an access token for a specific resource:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Thanks for this... will investigate asap. What confuses me is: how come login works just fine without these setup requirements? Surely if login gives me an access token, then signup should be able to do the same?

Comment: Authentication gives you an id token only. Authorisation to a resource gives you access tokens.